# Bacteria population growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, word-problem

> The population of bacteria triples each day on a petri dish. If it takes 20 days for the population of bacteria to fill the entire dish, how many days will it take bacteria to fill half of the petri dish?

- My doubt 1: if we don't have a initial population can be solve this problem?
  Like $A(d)$= initial population times $3^{20}$ days but as I don't have this I am stuck.
- My doubt 2: Also, can we assume a number for population at day 20 and move our way backwards?

Comment: Hint. Work backwards. On day 20, you have amount "1" (one petri dish). How much do you have on day 19? How about 18? etc ...

Comment: @MattiP. So on day 19 the bacteria will fill 1/3 of the petri dish and Now, I need to find how much time it will take them to fill 1/6 more so the total become 1/2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the population $N_t$ of bacteria after time (in days) $t$ with initial population $N_0$ be given by:
$$N_t = N_0 e^{\lambda t}$$
where $\lambda$  is a constant. It is given $N_1 = 3N_0 = N_0 e^{\lambda}$. From this you can rearrange terms to get $\lambda = \ln (3)$. This means:
$$N_t = N_0 e^{t \ln(3)} = N_03^t.$$

Let $M$ be the population that covers the whole petridish. It is given that $M = N_03^{20} \implies M/N_0 = 3^{20}$. The population that covers half the petridish should $M/2 = N_03^{T}$ where $T$ is the required time. $M/2N_0 = 3^{20}/2 = 3^{\log_3 (0.5)+ 20} = 3^T  \implies T = \log_3(0.5) + 20 = 20 - \log_3 (2).$

I think this answers your questions.

Comment: Re Doubt 1: You can see you don't need to know the initial population from the calculation. Re Doubt 2: I started with the population on the 20th day, and then I calculated backwards.

Answer (score 0):

> The population of bacteria triples each day on a petri dish.

Let $\{ a_n \}$ the population of bacteria on the n-th day.
We have $$a_{n+1} = 3 \cdot a_n$$
Furthermore, we have $$a_n = 3^{n-1} \cdot a_1$$

> If it takes 20 days for the population of bacteria to fills the entire dish.

Let $S$ the total population of bacteria when the entire dish is filled.
We have $$a_{20} \geqslant S > a_{19}$$
or $$3^{19} \cdot a_1 \geqslant S > 3^{18} \cdot a_1$$

> How many days it will take bacteria to fill half of the petri dish?

Just divide the inequity by 2, we have $$\frac{3^{19}}{2} a_1 \geqslant \frac{S}{2} > \frac{3^{18}}{2} a_1$$

Let $3^{n-1} = \frac{3^{18}}{2}$ and $3^{m-1} = \frac{3^{19}}{2}$, we have $n = 19 - log_3 2 \approx 18.369$ and $m = 20 - log_3 2 \approx 19.369$.

It's obvious that on the 19th day, the dish is half-filled.